# SSIS how to build unique filename in Expression

Tags: ssis, filenames

I would like to create random unique filename in SSIS using expression builder for Flat file connection Manager - ConnectionString.

Should be like: "Custom name" + "unique part" + "csv"

Actualy a timestamp in miliseconds would do.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you using the expression design to do that.

Here Im using the ExecutionGuid to generate the value. It may not be the best idea because the result is quite big but you can use datetime functions as well to create something on the format you desire:

[image]

Comment: But if I want to pass any value into this expression, is it possible? Example a variable in the Data flow task stores the "RowCount". Can I add this to the FlatFile header using expression builder?

Answer (score 2):

It's a litte convoluted thanks to all the REPLACEs, but you can use:

```
"Custom Name " + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((DT_WSTR, 50)(GETDATE()), "-",""), ".", ""), ":",""), 1, 18)  + ".csv"
```

as a starting point. This will return:

```
Custom Name 20120529 133526359.csv
```

as a possible filename. It's not 100% guaranteed unique, and it's obviously not random, but I think it's all that can be done just in an Expression. Alternatively, you can use a Script Task to generate a more random string using C#/VB.NET, write that into a variable and use the variable in your Expression.

Comment: thank you. I will use script task, but Diego has provided an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Format("Custom name{0}.csv", Path.GetRandomFileName());`

or

`string.Format("Custom name{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"));`

Answer (score 0):

This will be to get unique date time..

```
" + (DT_WSTR, 30)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE() + "_" + 
    (DT_WSTR, 05) DATEPART("Hh",GETDATE()) + 
    (DT_WSTR, 05) DATEPART("Mi",GETDATE()) + 
    (DT_WSTR, 05) DATEPART("Ss",GETDATE()) +
    ".csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was easy to find how to create the expression but difficult to find instructions on how to set your output filename to use this expression.  It is not a straightforward process.  Here is an answer to this problem.  I hope this helps somebody.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlgardner/2015/06/18/ssis-tip-using-a-file-path-parameter-for-multiple-flat-files/#comment-1755